# I want to implement a hello world process in bpel

Tags: eclipse, bpel, ode

I'm learning BPEL using the eclipse bpel designer

I have followed:
http://www-inf.int-evry.fr/SIMBAD/courses/doku.php?id=teaching_assistant:bpel:deploying_hello_world_bpel_process_with_eclipse_bpel_designer_and_apache_ode

to the letter(multiple times, double checking everything along the way

when I get to step 11 to test the process I open web services explorer, I type Hello ODE in the body of the request as instructed
when I click go, instead of getting a response with the string I had sent(Hello ODE)
I get the following error instead:
IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occured
404
Not found

I'm using eclipse kepler
Apache ODE 1.3.6eclipse bpel designer 1.0.4
tomcat 8
gentoo Linux

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the site you want to access does not exist on the tomcat server. Have you tried accessing  http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/HelloWorld via your browser?

Comment: I created that page, I still get nothing, I can't even access the index page, something might be wrong with my tomcat server

Comment: Yes, if you can not access that page this is most likely a problem with your tomcat server. You might check the server logs in order to verify that assumption.

Comment: that's all I have in the log
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2016:23:22:31 +0200] "POST /ode/processes/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1" 404 -
.......................................................................................................
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2016:23:22:44 +0200] "GET /ode/processes/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1" 404 -

................................................................................>
which isn't really helpful